# simple_form with Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, nested-attributes

I think I am going to ask a 2-part question; if this should be separated into 2 questions, my apologies.

First off, I am trying to store courses into a `course` table (course_name, instructor, start_time, end_time, etc...) which would have an ActiveRecord relation with `course_days` (`course_id` and `day` which corresponds with the day of the week => 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc...).  My end goal is to display these as a schedule in FullCalendar, which is why I think separating the `course` and `course_days` into two tables with an ActiveRecord relation would be best.  **Using Rails, is this a good way to achieve this?**

If so, secondly, I'm using Simple Form to add the following data to 2 tables: `course` and `course_days`.  And I think I am getting close.  I am just having some difficulty adding the `course_days` (e.g., 3 separate rows will be added to `course_days` if "Monday", "Tuesday" and "Thursday" are checked.

Here is what I am currently working with:

```
#new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @course, html: { autocomplete: 'off' } do |f| %>
<%= f.input :title, label: 'Class Name', placeholder: 'Class Name' %>
<%= f.input :instructor, placeholder: "Instructor Name" %>
<%= f.input :instructor_email, placeholder: 'Instructor Email' %>
<%= f.input :building, placeholder: 'Building' %>
<%= f.input :room, placeholder: 'Room' %>
<%= f.input :semester do %>
    <%= f.select :semester_id, @semesters.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] } %>
<% end %>
<%= f.simple_fields_for :course_days do |p| %>
    <%= p.input :day, :as => :boolean %>
 <% end %>
<%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

```
#app/models/course.rb
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_days
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :course_days
end
```

```
#app/models/course_day.rb
class CourseDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
end
```

```
#app/controllers/courses_controller.rb

  def new
   @course = Course.new
   7.times  { @course.course_days.build } #For 7 days of the week??
   @semesters = Semester.all() 
  end

 def create
   @course = Course.new(course_params)
   if @course.save
     redirect_to action: 'new'
     flash[:notice] = "Course Created."
   else
     render :new
   end
 end

 def course_params
  params.require(:course).permit!
 end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
The issues I am having with the form above:
1) How do I generate 7 checkboxes with an assigned attribute to determine if its a Monday, Tuesday, etc?
2) Using the nested attributes, it is only submitting one record to the database, even if multiple checkboxes are checked.

**Edit 2**

So, essentially, when that form is submitted, I would like the database tables to look something like this:

```
  courses: id => 14, name => Bio 101, start_time => 08:00:00, end_time 09:00:00

  course_days: id => 11, course_id => 14, day => 1  (For monday)
  course_days: id => 12, course_id => 14, day => 3  (For wednesday)
  course_days: id => 13, course_id => 14, day => 5  (For friday)
```

Comment: seems a good idea, what is exactly your concern? or problem?

Comment: Would you be interested in this gem: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form ? I think it may help you to achieve what you want. What I would do is... when a user check a 'day checkbox', it clicks (using coffeescript) on a hidden 'link_to_add' button and prefilter one of the new nested attribute by the corresponding day value. Do you think this gem may help you? Do you want me to write a detailed answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take into account that having another table, will need to fetch that rows from the DB.

So when you ask for a course, you will need a maximum of 7 more hits for knowing the course days.

I suggest that you have a `days` column *in* the Course model. This column will save the selected days in comma separated values.

This way you don't need `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. In this case, what you need to do is to populate the Course.days columns with the checkboxes values using a `before_validation` callback.

Comment: I think this is a good start. You could also use the easy_roles gem and take a role as a day..the easy_roles gem uses therefore a bitmask. Check it out on github. You only need one db attribute and no association. Just use the roles in your days context.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but  what about:

```
   7.times  { |i| @course.course_days.build day: i } #For 7 days of the week??
```

This way you would have 7 instances with different values of days. You could use `i+1` to start in 1.

I suppose this would send something like:

```
{
  "course" => {
    "course_days_attributes" =>{
      "0" => { "day" => "1"},
      "1" => { "day" => "5"},
    }
  }
}
```

Try this just for testing, then you can refactor:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :course_days do |p| %>
  <%= p.input :day, :as => :check_box, input_html: { value: f.object.course_days.day } %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know if you can use `p.object.day` instead of `f.object.course_days.day`. This should be automatic though.

Another thing I would try would be this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :course_days, f.object.course_days do |p| %>
```

But actually I can't explain what exactly is happening.

I am not sure about this though.

Comment: Thanks, this looks a little closer.  It is returning this array: `course[course_days_attributes][0][day]:0
course[course_days_attributes][0][day]:1
course[course_days_attributes][1][day]:0
course[course_days_attributes][1][day]:1
course[course_days_attributes][2][day]:0
course[course_days_attributes][3][day]:0
course[course_days_attributes][4][day]:0
course[course_days_attributes][5][day]:0
course[course_days_attributes][6][day]:0`   And in the DB, it is submitting 7 rows, all with the correct `course_id`, but then the `day` column is just a 1 or 0.  Any other ideas on this?

Comment: I don't know, that seems related with `boolean` you have there. See my update.

Comment: now it's passing things like 'course[course_day_ids][]:1
course[course_day_ids][]:3', which looks like it's trying to associate with an actual `course_days` `id`.  I've updated my question again to show what I am trying to achieve on the DB side.

Comment: Thank for your update.  It still is not working with either way.  For both I get: `undefined method `day' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::...`.  I'm guessing there's no way to do this with Rails, because it doesn't seem like it would be the most complicated thing to carry out.

Answer (score 0):

First off, simple_form has collections for inputs

So

```
<%= f.input :semester do %>
  <%= f.select :semester_id, @semesters.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] } %>
<% end %>
```

you can write as

```
<%= f.input :semester, collection: @semesters %>
```

Second, to get days as boolean you can do something like this:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :course_days do |p| %>
  <%= p.input :day, collection: [['Monday',1],['Tuesday',2][so forth]], as: :check_boxes %>
<% end %>
```